# Program adds '\' before ':' when writing .properties file in Java

Tags: java, postgresql, properties, io

I'm trying to update my database.properties file in my program. However,
it seems Java is adding additional character on my properties file.

Here's a snippet of my code.

```
Properties props = new Properties();

        String propsFileName = "src/resources/properties/" + "database.properties";

        String[] property = new String[4];

        property[0] = "database.properties";
        property[1] = url.getText();
        property[2] = username.getText();
        property[3] = password.getText();

            try {

                FileInputStream configStream = new FileInputStream(propsFileName);
                props.load(configStream);
                configStream.close();

                props.setProperty("jdbc.driverClassName", Commons.driverClassName);
                props.setProperty("jdbc.url", property[1]);
                props.setProperty("jdbc.username", property[2]);
                props.setProperty("jdbc.password", property[3]);
                props.setProperty("jdbc.comment", comments.getText());

                FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(propsFileName);
                props.store(output, null);
                output.close();

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I have this output on my console which is to check if I get the string that I wanted,

> Properties = org.postgresql.Driver,
>   jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.1:1234/db, username,
>   password, null Program Ran on Fri Jun 23 16:00:37 PHT 2017 by
>   user=xngapp234

However, in my database.properties file, I'm getting this output.

```
jdbc.url=jdbc\:postgresql\://192.168.1.1\:1234/db
jdbc.username=username
jdbc.password=password
jdbc.comment=
jdbc.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
```

It adds '\' before the ':' which always gives me an error. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: In `\:` is the ``\`` not *before* the `:`?

Comment: Unrelated: your usage of that string array simply doesn't make much sense. It rather confuses your code. It is not good style to use slot 0 as file name, whereas the other 3 slots represent values to print into that thing. If at all, consider using a `Map<String, String>` instead: the key represents the property name, and the value, well the value. Or just drop that array completely. It doesn't add any value to your current code.

Comment: What is the problem? Why do you think, the added backslash is causing it?

Comment: This is the normal escaping of  `:` in java properties files. `props.load` should retrieve the correct values though .

Comment: Hi all. @GhostCat I will consider your suggestion thank you! I just tried to store it on a string instead of getting it directly through .getText(), but still got error. Thank you!

Comment: @Berger so it's normal to have /: in my properties file right? An xml file is reading the .properties file. I can't connect to database when there's /: in it.

Comment: Yes it is normal, as @sruetti says in his answer, the file is meant to be read through the `Properties` methods, that know how things are escaped in the file .

Comment: So, the real answer: do a bit of research the next time; and study the javadoc of the classes you are using ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to store and load properties from a Java program, everything is working as supposed! Your code shows that the url is read without the backslashes - just as you stored it.

As Berger writes, this is the normal escaping in java.properties files. This is documented in the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store(java.io.Writer,%20java.lang.String)) of Properties.store():

> [...] The key and element characters #, !, =, and : are written with a
>   preceding backslash to ensure that they are properly loaded. [...]

If you try to use the Properties class to write a file to be consumed by a non-Java program, you're out of luck as that's not what this class is intended for. You'll need to use another library for that.

The javadoc states

> The Properties class represents a persistent set of properties.

The ".properties"-format is just one representation of a set of properties (with an XML format being another).